# Get Unique conversation between users in messages table mysql using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a messages table with following columns

```
id | message | toId | fromId | {few more columns}
```

I am trying to list recent conversations list. Consider a case where i with id 1 has a chat with id 2

some rows will be like

```
1 | First Message | 1 | 2 | {few more columns}
2 | Sec   Message | 2 | 1 | {few more columns}
3 | Third Message | 1 | 3 | {few more columns}
```

Here is my code to get unique conversations based on messages

```
$result = $this->Message->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => $conditions,       
                     'joins' => array(
                                        array(
                                                'table' => 'users',
                                                'alias' => 'from',
                                                'type' =>  'LEFT',
                                                'conditions' => array(
                                                    'from.id = Message.from',                                                   
                                              )
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                                'table' => 'users',
                                                'alias' => 'to',
                                                'type' =>  'LEFT',
                                                'conditions' => array(
                                                    'to.id = Message.to',                                                   
                                              )
                                        ),
                    ),
                    'fields' => array('from.id','from.firstname','from.username', 'from.lastname','from.imagePath',
                        'to.id','to.firstname','to.username', 'to.lastname','to.imagePath',
                        'Message.*'), 
                    'order' => array('Message.created DESC'),
                    'limit' => 20,
                    'offset' => $offset * 20,                    
        ));
```

This above code is just simply fetching all the messages and attaching their users. However i am not sure how can i put condition based on unique conversations.

In above example there are two conversations, between 1 and 2 and between 1 and 3

How can i list only 2 messages in response that have unique combination

> "SELECT `From`.`id`, `From`.`firstname`, `From`.`username`,
>   `From`.`lastname`, `From`.`imagePath`, `To`.`id`, `To`.`firstname`,
>   `To`.`username`, `To`.`lastname`, `To`.`imagePath`, `Message`.* FROM
>   `xxxx`.`messages` AS `Message` LEFT JOIN `xxxx`.`users` AS `To`
>   ON (`Message`.`to` = `To`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `xxxx`.`users` AS `From`
>   ON (`Message`.`from` = `From`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `xxxx`.`messages` AS
>   `message` ON (((`Message`.`from` = `message`.`from` AND `Message`.`to`
>   = `message`.`to`) OR (`Message`.`from` = `message`.`to`   AND `Message`.`to`  = `message`.`from`)) AND `Message`.`created` <
>   `message`.`created`)  WHERE `message`.`id` IS NULL   ORDER BY
>   `Message`.`created` DESC  LIMIT 20",

Comment: Not sure about the cakephp's query builder but it can be done via plain sql, Also for unique combination like for user 1 and 2 there 2 conversation which conversation you want latest or oldest based on created ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i can convert plain sql to cake, yes latest would be preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the latest conversation from messages per unique toId and fromId you can use self join with some conditional clauses in `on()` part

```
SELECT m.*
FROM 
message m
LEFT JOIN message m1 ON (
  (
    (m.fromId  = m1.fromId  AND m.toId  = m1.toId )
                          OR
    (m.fromId  = m1.toId  AND m.toId  = m1.fromId  )
  )
  AND m.created < m1.created
)
WHERE m1.id IS NULL
ORDER BY m.id
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/MRTTG12657)

Later on you could join you users table with above query to get user related information

Comment: it works great, however its getting all recent messages of all types of users, is that possible to limit to specific users e.g i need to see my own user with id = 2

Comment: @MuhammadUmar yes you could add another filter `AND 2 in (m.toId,m.fromId )` for user id  = 2